# Have to delete the rows with specific character's in the row

Tags: r

I have a data in which for last two years every month I have to delete the rows with certain characters

I have tried these but I have to repeat the code for 2 years every month, I need to do with the help of for loop.

> SEPT <- datetable2 [(!(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18== "risk30") &
>   !(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18=="risk60") &
>   !(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18=="risk90")
>
> SEPT <- datetable2 [(!(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18== "risk30") &
>   !(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18=="risk60") &
>   !(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18=="risk90") &
>   !(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18=="risk120") & !

I need it to be done in simple for loop please guide me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please try to reduce complexity linked to your specific problem so that it is more general and easier for us to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generate labels to exclude using `paste0` and then use `%in%` to find elements with the desired labels

```
i = 5
sept <- datetable2[!(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18 %in% paste0("risk", (1:i)*30)),]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but is there any possibility to do it in for loop, Because i have to remove it for 2 years which means i have to repeat the code for 24 times

Comment: `for(i in 1:24){datetable2 <- datetable2[!(datetable2$DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18 %in% paste0("risk", (1:i)*30)),]}`

Comment: Hi Thanks for the help,but i tried to do it without using the month, $DLYRISK.EOM.Sep18 , I tried do for the whole data datetable2 its not working help me with these